# How to Bind the Value to a column on dropdown selection change in grid view+Telerik+Mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik-mvc

I am using Telerik Controls in my project, I want to bind value to a column on Dropdown selection changed in BatchEditing of Telerik Grid view.

Example: I have Product_cd, Product_Description where Product_cd is a Dropdown and I have to fill Product_Description in next column while selection changed.

Help me in this scenario. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To do so you will need to combine the usage of the [saveCell and editCell](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#ClientMethods) methods. 
In the logic you are going to implement always keep the Grid with only single cell into edit mode.
Also you will probably need to handle the DropDownList [OnChange](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-combobox-client-api-and-events.html#OnChange) event.